# Application File Not Valid on XBAP

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xbap

CilckOnce Application (WPF web browser application)

I have hosted Xbap Application on Windows Server & it is working on all clients: Windows 7 & windows 8x & 10x

Developed with VS2008, .net Framework 3.5 SP1

But some client machines with latest Windows 10 Pro (version 1703, build :15063.608) with latest IE is not working. It is downloading, but at the end it is giving following error:

Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.

> An exception occurred while downloading the application. Following failure messages were detected: Exception occurred loading manifest from file intxxxx.dll: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. Cannot load internal manifest from component file.

Platform Details 
    windows : 10.0.15063.0 (win32NT)
    Common L R  " 4.0.30319
    System.Deployement.dll :4.7.2046

The same dll in working as desktop application, but in browser giving error

Please help me to resolve the issue

All other client machine is working properly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of the windows Defender was blocking to install from Browser. Only allowed to install app from app store

Disable or add exclusion List in Windows Defender or antivirus 
also compile without any .Net assembly Protector ( Compress or .Net Reactor ..etc.)

Thanks to all